# How do I install a new language and enable it from the command line?

Tags: 22.04, language-support, locale

This seems to be undocumented. The problem is that I have a headless server, which was minimally installed with one language, but must be reconfigured to a second language; I need to script this process. This requires several steps, but I don't have quite enough information to do this. In the steps below, I start with UK English, and want to end up with (for example) French Canadian:

**1: Find all potential languages**

The languages seem to be listed in `/usr/share/language-selector/data/languagelist`. I can't find any docs on what this file is, or its format, but there's a useful [Debian script](https://sources.debian.org/src/localechooser/2.104/languagemap/) which gives some clues. If I grep for 'French' I get:

```
French;1;fr;fr_FR.UTF-8;fr;FR;fr_FR:fr:en_GB:en;kbd=lat9u-16(utf8)
```

The textual description is column 1 (`French`, and the user gets this option in the web front-end). The language appears to be column 5 (`fr`; the Deb script says that col 3 is `DEFAULT_COUNTRY` and 5 is `LANGUAGELIST`).

**First problem**: this is not a UTF-8 file. The Ubuntu installer lists languages such as Ελληνικά, so it does something I don't know about.

**2: Install missing language packs**

Get the list of missing packages for language `fr`, and install them:

```
$ sudo apt -y install $(check-language-support -l fr)
```

**3: Regenerate locales**

Uncomment the required locale in `/etc/locale.gen`, and then generate the new locales with `locale-gen`.

**Second problem**: `fr` is not a locale; it's a language. The French entries in `/etc/locale.gen` are:

```
# fr_BE ISO-8859-1
# fr_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8
# fr_BE@euro ISO-8859-15
# fr_CA ISO-8859-1
# fr_CA.UTF-8 UTF-8
# fr_CH ISO-8859-1
# fr_CH.UTF-8 UTF-8
# fr_FR ISO-8859-1
# fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8
# fr_FR@euro ISO-8859-15
# fr_LU ISO-8859-1
# fr_LU.UTF-8 UTF-8
# fr_LU@euro ISO-8859-15
```

...but only one of these (`fr_FR.UTF-8`) appears in `languagelist`, so how do I know that I have to uncomment one of the `fr_CA` entries to get 'French Canadian'? Or should I just uncomment the entry given by column 4 in `languagelist` and accept that I can't have a variation of French?

**4: Update locales**

This at least is easy - just run

```
 $ sudo update-locale LANG=fr_CA.UTF-8
```

Before this step, `/etc/default/locale` contained `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`; afterwards, it contained `LANG=fr_CA.UTF-8`.

Comment: There are two problems, as per the bold statements. Ubuntu installation has a different source for the language list, so does this differently - how? I've just guessed that the source is `languagelist`, but it can't be. Secondly, the procedure can't automate a language installation from the first field of `languagelist`, because it doesn't include the full locale information: it only has a subset. So, it may look like a solution, but it isn't.

Comment: OTOH, it *may* be a valid solution if you assume that you can only install a small subset of languages - one Spanish, one French, one English, and so on, and you don't care about the UTF-8 languages in an Ubuntu install.